# Unable to bind MenuItem IsChecked attribute in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind IsChecked it is binding value on second click. Following is my xaml

```
 <ContextMenu><MenuItem Header="Type"  IsCheckable="True"  IsChecked="{Binding isTypeChecked}" Checked="Type_Click"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Price"  IsCheckable="True"  IsChecked="{Binding isPriceChecked}" Checked="Price_Click"/>
                                    <MenuItem Header="Category"  IsCheckable="True"  IsChecked="{Binding isCategoryChecked}" Checked="Category_Click"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
```

xaml.cs as belows

```
private void Type_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainViewModel _mainWindowViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = _mainWindowViewModel;
        _mainWindowViewModel.isTypeChecked = true;
        _mainWindowViewModel.isPriceChecked = false;
        _mainWindowViewModel.isCategoryChecked = false;

        ItemsGrid.Columns[3].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ItemsGrid.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        ItemsGrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

ViewModel as below

```
 public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel() { }       

    private bool _isTypeChecked;
    public bool isTypeChecked { get { return _isTypeChecked; } set { _isTypeChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("isTypeChecked"); } }
    private bool _isPriceChecked;
    public bool isPriceChecked { get { return _isPriceChecked; } set { _isPriceChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("isPriceChecked"); } }
    private bool _isCategoryChecked;
    public bool isCategoryChecked { get { return _isCategoryChecked; } set { _isCategoryChecked = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("isCategoryChecked"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName) { PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }

}
```

Unable to find what wrong i am doing
Please help

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: on 2nd click it shows checked option even i have put break point on model property and it is not hitting

Comment: Could you describe it with details, I really don't understand what do you mean by "shows checked option"

Comment: tick option must come when IsChecked="{Binding true}" but it is coming on 2nd click

Comment: look in the Output window if there are binding errors

Comment: Why are you creating a MainViewModel in the Click event handler...?

Comment: @mm8 then what is should do?

Comment: How do you set the DataContext of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Initially your property will return null. I'm not sure this is causing the problem you're seeing but you should initialise the backing variables. Presumably you will want false to start with.

```
private bool _isTypeChecked =false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DataContext = this;` in your MainViewModel. I once had a similar issue and with this little addition, it worked.